# Cannot change options in mounting ntfs partition for rw

Tags: debian, mount, fstab, fuse, ntfs-3g

I need to mount a ntfs volume for read & write for a particular group of users, so I tried putting in this line in `/etc/fstab`: (I have also tried UUID but it was the same result)

```
/dev/sda1     /mnt/userdisk    ntfs-3g    uid=1001,gid=1001,dmask=0002,fmask=0003        0       0
```

Also, I tried the manual mount command with the option `-o uid=1001,gid=1001,dmask=0002,fmask=0003`

However, on both occasions, the result came out as the following without any of the options I supplied when I checked the mounted device (as well as in `/etc/mtab`):

```
 /dev/sda1 on /mnt/userdisk type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

I have also tried using UUID instead of `/dev/sda1`, the "permissions" options instead

So it seems that somehow it always uses a default set of options. Could it be because of the fuse settings or the default script? Any idea how I get the options I need applied?